# why a have this error in Java eclipse STS?

Tags: java

Trying to figure the cause for this error, any solution?
ecplise java sts

*"The method getPrincipal() is undefined for the type Principal"*

```
    <layout:put block="x-brand-options">
<c:set var="name" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.name}"/>
<div class="right menu">
  <div class="ui dropdown item" id="cbo-profile">
    <i class="user icon"></i>
    ${name} <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item">Perfil</a>
      <div class="divider" style="margin:0px;"></div>
      <form action="/logout"
        method="post"
        name="logoutform">
        <input type="hidden"
          name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
          value="${_csrf.token}"/>
      </form>
      <a class="item" onclick="document.logoutform.submit();">
        <i class="sign out icon"></i>
        Cerrar Sesión
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</layout:put>
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The method getPrincipal() is undefined for the type Principal index.jsp

Comment: that probably means that the getter is not properly created in the entity file of the Principal